# Button that detects for value

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this html

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="">
<span id="currenticon">Test</span>
<a href="#" id="button">Set</a>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

and this javascript

```
if(document.getElementById('button').clicked == true)
{
   var inputted = document.getElementById("textbox").getAttribute("value")
   document.getElementById("currenticon").innerHTML = inputted;
}
```

So it is supposed to do:
For example, I type in "Hello" in the textbox and I click the button (the a tag), it should set currenticon's text to Hello, but it doesn't for some reason

Edit: I updated the javascript to

```
if(document.getElementById('button').clicked == true){
   var inputted = document.getElementById("textbox").innerText
   document.getElementById("currenticon").innerHTML = inputted;
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to put a ; after the ".innerText" but I put it and it still doesn't work

Sorry if this is weird, I'm new to javascript :)

EDIT: I got it working now

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="">
    <span id="currenticon">Test</span>
    <span id="button" onclick="recieved()">Set</span>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
function recieved() {
   var inputted = document.getElementById("textbox").value
   document.getElementById("currenticon").innerHTML = inputted;
}
```

Comment: A `clicked` property for HTMLAnchorElement does not exist. Plus, a "static" if that gets evaluated one single time when this code first runs, won't notice any clicks happening later. Go read up on the basics of _event handling_.

Comment: And the user input from an input field or textarea is not read via `innerText`, but via `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links do not have a `clicked` property. If they did, then it would be `false` at the time your JavaScript runs to test what the value is.

If you want something to happen in response to a click, then you need [an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

---

Links are elements designed to take the user to a new URL. If you want something for the user to click on that does not go to a new URL, then use [a `<button type="button">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), not a link.

---

The `value` attribute sets the **default** value for an element.

Typing into the input does not change the `value` attribute.

You need the `value` **property**.

```
  document.getElementById("textbox").value
```

---

The `innerText` property gives you the descendant nodes of an element converted to plain text.

```
<p>this text for example</p>
```

An `<input>` element doesn't have descendant nodes so doesn't have `innerText`.

You need the `value` property.

---

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const input = document.getElementById('textbox');
const icon = document.getElementById('currenticon');
const updateValue = () => {
    icon.innerText = input.value;
};
button.addEventListener('click', updateValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="">
<span id="currenticon">Test</span>
<button type="button" id="button">Set</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',() => {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value
document.getElementById("currenticon").innerHTML = inputValue;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="">
<span id="currenticon">Test</span>
<a href="#" id="button">Set</a>
```

This is how you need to do this

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function(){ document.querySelector('#currenticon').textContent = document.getElementById('textbox').value; });